# Linux/RedHat - Yum install tab completion

Tags: yum, redhat-enterprise-linux

I had been using Ubuntu and recently migrated to RedHat.
The `apt-get install` auto completion is very handy, so I supposed `yum install` should have this function as well, but seemed it doesn't.
Is there tab completion for package name of `yum install` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
yum install bash-completion
```

Then logout console or close command line and log back in.
Than try:

```
$ yum in[TAB][TAB]
info     install

$ yum ins[TAB]  ## and you get "yum install"
```